# About checking numbers only in input on html

Tags: html

I've tried the below code:

```
    var nNoT;

    nNoT=Number(ObjVal("qTo")); alert(nNoT); 
    if (nNoT=="NaN"||ObjVal("qTo")==null||nNoT==0){ alert("Not number!"); return;}
            else alert("Number!")
```

I want to check for numbers only for "qTo" which transmit to me from another slave device. And if it is not a number, it will show "Not number!".

But, this code seems like not working. I key in "aaaa" for "qTo" and the "alert(nNoT)" show me it is "NaN", but it alert "Number!". What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing against the string "NaN" won't work.  Use the `isNaN()` function.

```
if (isNaN(nNoT) || ObjVal("qTo")==null || nNoT==0)
```